# Need to access True or False from Sql Case

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Sql Case method am declaring the true or false condition, but i need to design that true or false as icon(correct / wrong icon) . 
1.Bellow i have attached my .netC# code

```
 char c = 'A';
    int Role = 1, Value;
    string RoleMenu = "";
    this.str_RoleKey = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RoleKey"].ToString();
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)   
    {
        if (dr["RoleKey"].ToString() != "")
        {
            this.str_Case += " ,case when " + c + ".MenuKey is null then 'false' else 'true' end '" + Role + "' ";
            this.str_Join += " left outer join (select * from MenuRole where RoleKey='" + this.str_RoleKey + "') " + c + " on Me.MenuKey = " + c + ".MenuKey ";

            RoleMenu += "<td>%%"+ Role +"%%</td>";
            c++;
            Role++;
        }

    }

    RoleMenu = "<td>%%MenuName%%</td>" + RoleMenu;

    string str_sql1 = " select Me.MenuKey,Me.MenuName "
        + this.str_Case
        + " from Menu Me"
        + this.str_Join;
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you try to explain better?

Comment: Menu visibility need to show with icon (right/wrong),  true/ false i can get from the sql case and i need to convert that true/ false into icon - @KobyDouek

Answer (score 0):

Rather than return a `varchar` ('true' or 'false') from your SQL, instead have it return a `bit`, with 1 being true, 0 being false.